# Really confused about how to set height and width as a percentage for my carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, height, carousel

I am trying to set the width of my carousel to take up 100% of the width of the screen while the height takes up 35% of the screen from the top. I have tried numerous attempts to use % with height, but it just doesn't work.

This is my css:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0;
}

.carousel-slide, .carousel-image, .carousel-inner{
    height: 35%;
    width: 100%;
}

/*carousel-image is the class for the images placed in the carousel*/
```

The reason why I dont want to use px or em is because I want the carousel to take up 35% of the screen regardless of the device the website is being used on (desktop browser, ipad, smartphone...)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using 35 viewport height and 100 viewport width instead and see if that works.

```
.carousel-slide, .carousel-image, .carousel-inner{
    height: 35vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```